# Module not found: Can't resolve 'apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common' apex chart module not found

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Failed to compile

./node_modules/react-apexcharts/dist/react-apexcharts.min.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common' in

> 'Z:\React\misc-examples\node_modules\react-apexcharts\dist'

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
npm install --save react-apexcharts apexcharts
```

or

```
yarn add react-apexcharts apexcharts
```

Comment: I rolled your edit back. Please don't incorporate others' answers into your own.

Answer (score 1):

```
yarn add --save react-apexcharts apexcharts
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.